# Delete zeros from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

This question was asked in multiple other posts but I could not get any of the methods to work. This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4.5],[1,2,0,4,5]])
```

I would like to know how I can either:

1) Delete rows that contain any/all zeros
2) Delete columns that contain any/all zeros

In order to delete rows that contain any zeros, this worked:

```
df2 = df[~(df == 0).any(axis=1)]
df2 = df[~(df == 0).all(axis=1)]
```

But I cannot get this to work column wise. I tried to set axis=0 but that gives me this error:

```
__main__:1: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need `loc` for this:

```
df
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  1  2  0  4  5

df.loc[:, ~(df == 0).any(0)]  # notice the :, this means we are indexing on the columns now, not the rows
   0  1  3  4
0  1  2  4  5
1  1  2  4  5
```

Direct indexing defaults to indexing on the rows. You are trying to index a dataframe with only two rows using `[0, 1, 3, 4]`, so `pandas` is warning you about that.

Comment: Given the sequential nature of the data, I believe it was supposed to end in `4, 5` instead of `4.5`. Also, I don't believe you need the zero in your `any` method, i.e. just `any()` should work.

Comment: @Alexander heheh, never would've realised. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexander: good catch. Actually that is how it originally happened a while back, but I keep it that way ever since to create a missing value so I can test dropna() every now and then, I tend to forget how the axis are defined within dropna().

Comment: @NiccolaTartaglia Perhaps best to explicitly add `np.NaN` as the last element in the first row.

Comment: @Alexander:  oh yeah, that is a better alternative. Thanks for pointing that out!!!